# Running Ghost in Github - Error: Cannot find module '/home/runner/work/website/website/package.json'

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions, ghost-blog

I'm trying to build a website using Ghost and followed the tutorial to connect it with GitHub exactly. When I run the code in the `.github/workflows/main.yml` file I get the error:

```
Run TryGhost/action-deploy-theme@v1.4.1
Error: Cannot find module '/home/runner/work/website/website/package.json'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at main (/home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js:1560:62)
    at Object.104 (/home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js:1578:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js:24:31)
    at startup (/home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js:43:19)
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js:47:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js:50:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/runner/work/_actions/TryGhost/action-deploy-theme/v1.4.1/dist/index.js'
  ]
}
```

If anyone knows how to fix this problem I'd appreciate you letting me know :)

Comment: It's tough to say why this happens without seeing the code that causes it. Can you edit your question to include the relevant code (preferably as a [mre])?

Comment: The only code I used was whats shown in [this tutorial](https://ghost.org/integrations/github/) (Under the section 'Install the Ghost Theme Deploy Action')

Comment: Could you add the repository structure (where you used the action) to the question please?